# Javascript onclick send event with parameters

Tags: javascript, php

I have onclick event for button. I have to send 3 parameters to the javascript function. 2 are interger and third one is string.

I am getting error like this.

> ReferenceError: PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT is not defined

PHP code as follows.

```
foreach ($courier->service_types as $service_types) {
    $service_type=$service_types->service_name;

    $html .= '</tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><center>' . $service_types->service_name . '</center></td>
    <td><center>' . $service_types->rate_breakup->total_charge . '</center></td>
    <td><center>' . $service_types->rate_breakup->base_rate . '</center></td>
    <td><center>' . $service_types->rate_breakup->fuel_surcharge . '</center></td>
    <th><center><strong>'.$service_types->rate_breakup->goods_services_tax . '</strong></center></th>
    <td><center><button class="submit" id="' . $courier->courier_id . '" onclick="send_to_courier(' . $courier->courier_id . ',' . $service_types->service_id . ',' . $service_type . ')">Select</button></center></td>';                                
}
```

My javascript function as follows

```
function send_to_courier(courier_id,service_id,service_type){
    alert(service_type);
}
```

Comment: Strings needs to be quoted. But you can also create a listener instead of using `onclick`.

Comment: I tried these onclick="send_to_courier('.$courier->courier_id.','.$service_types->service_id.','".$service_type."')" but not worked

Comment: You need to escape them, since you're already in a quoted string. `\"` instead of `"` around the string.

Comment: Did you view the result first in the inspect element? Also do you happen to have a variable call to PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT in your script?

Comment: `PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT` is not defined or used anywhere in the provided code ..?

Comment: <button class="submit" id="'.$courier->courier_id.'" onclick="send_to_zepo('.$courier->courier_id.','.$service_types->service_id.',\"'.$service_type.'\")">Select</button>  i tried this one , its also not worked.

Comment: can you post your whole JavaScript code? maybe you are calling PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT somewhere.

Comment: PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT is a string. I need that value in javascript function

Comment: The error message says `PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT` being a variable name, please check the code. Take a look at the source code or DevTools in your browser, and find out what PHP has actually printed to the document.

Comment: Can someone vote this down. The person asking not even listing to what we said.

Comment: Here my problem is PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT is not a constant , its varying like STANDARD , BY AIR etc. In that case in my javascript function i called as service_type to catch that as string.

Comment: Like I said, take a look a the rendered code in your browser, you're messing up with quoting in `onclick` attribute. `PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT` might be a string in PHP code, but it becames a variable reference in the rendered JavaScript. Actually Anagha`s answer is correct, though it's not very detailed.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion , I tried to post complete javascript code but it showed me an error like , your question is full of code.

Comment: Did you tried finding if you are calling a PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT variable>

Comment: Error is somewhere else .. `PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT` is not used here

Answer (score 0):

the string parameter should be in quotes. As you are already using quests to append variable name you can use like this "'.$service_type.'"

Comment: you see the error is not related to the answer you proposed. And JavaScript variable can handle String/Non-String variable. So problem is not in printing the output

Comment: I tried your code  , It resulted like this <button class="submit" id="1" onclick="send_to_zepo(1,1, " priority_overnight")"="">Select</button> . its not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code as follows. Its worked now.

```
  $html .="<button class='submit' id='".$courier->courier_id."' onclick='send_to_zepo(\"$courier->courier_id\", \"$service_types->service_id\",\"$service_type\");'>Select</button></center></td>";
```